# Find dimensions of object that has display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the right side of my page I have a list of sponsors.

My active page area (left side) height varies from page to page, depending on the story it contains every time.

I want the list's height to match the live pages height, so I thought I'd always show the main sponsors, and for the rest of them, I'd hide them, and show exactly as many as I can each time.

My markup looks like this:

```
<div id="xorigoi">
<a class="basic"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/1.png"></a>
<a class="basic"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/2.png"></a>
<a class="basic"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/3.png"></a>
<a class="rest"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/4.png"></a>
<a class="rest"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/5.png"></a>
<a class="rest"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/6.png"></a>
<a class="rest"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/7.png"></a>
<a class="rest"><img src="/views/images/adjustable/sideXorigoi/8.png"></a>
</div>
```

Every image is a link to each sponsor's site. Every image has it's own height.

Elements that have the class `.rest` are hidden using `display: none`

I'm trying to calculate if adding the new image will make the list longer than the page, but since the elements are hidden, offsetHeight = 0.

What can I do?

My javascript/jquery code so far looks like this:

```
$(
function(){
var containerHeight = $('#mainPageContainer')[0].offsetHeight; // total height of page
var xorigoi = $('#mainRightSide .rest'); // select the sponsors
var newHeight = 1062; // this is the right side height I am already using
$.each( xorigoi , function( index ){
if( newHeight + heightOfNewElement > containerHeight ){
return false; // break each
}
xorigoi.eq(index).css('display','block'); // display the sponsor
newHeight = newHeight + heightOfNewElement;
})
}
)
```

So bottomline, how can I get heightOfNewElement in the function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of display none, you could consider moving your elements outside the viewport. For example:

```
.rest {position:absolute;top:-9999px;}
```

Comment: I won't go with that if the other solutions work as they seem cleaner, but I like the thought and actually I should have thought of this in the first place.

Comment: @AnPel I don't think there's anything dirty in this approach. It is quite common for inline navigation, and more ARIA compliant than display none. I wrote about it here: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2011/05/03/easy-tabs-and-accessibility/

Comment: Come to think about it, I could set the container to overflow:hidden and remove display:none from the images. Then I'll just use offsetHeight of each image to adjust container height so that sponsors enter the viewport as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Since JavaScript is single-threaded, the browser will not redraw while it is executing. As such, you can safely set the elements to `display:block`, measure them, then hide them again and the user will be none the wiser.

Comment: You can add `visibility:hidden;` if it makes you feel better or to avoid a possible visual glitch.

Comment: @Kolink—You should not set display to "block", set it to "" (empty string) because the display property may not be block by default or by CSS, it might be [inline, list-item, table, inline-table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html#display) and so on.

Comment: +1 interesting trick. Same comment as @RobG, I'd rather use display "".

Answer (score 1):

Guess this will help you.

```
console.log(getDimensions($('#myElement')));

function getDimensions(element){
    var tempElement = $(element).clone();
    $(tempElement).css('display','block').css('visibility','hidden');
    $(document.body).append(tempElement);
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.width = $(tempElement).width();
    obj.height = $(tempElement).height();
    $(tempElement).remove();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You can't reliably determine the size of an element that isn't in the DOM since it wont inherit cascading styles or be constrained by the flow of other elements.

Comment: @RobG. I didn't get you. Actually, its working when i tried it. Can you give me a scenario where it could go wrong?

Comment: Further to what I posted above, copying the element and appending it to the end of the document means it won't inherit the same cascading styles, unless the source element was at the end of the document, and it may not have an appropriate parent (e.g. TR or TD element).